# StAX - how to set XMLInputFactory.IS_VALIDATING to true?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stax

this is my first time using StAX for parsing XML documents (still in the learning stage).  During the process to parse an XML document using XMLStreamReader and generate a copy of the document using XMLStreamWriter, I encountered the following warning represented as a comment in the output of the writer:

```
 <!-- Exception scanning External DTD Subset.  True contents of DTD cannot be determined.  Processing will continue as XMLInputFactory.IS_VALIDATING == false. -->
```

I understood the cause of the warning, but I wanted it to become an error rather than silently became a warning, so then I tried to set XMLInputFactory.IS_VALIDATING to true:

```
 XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
 factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_VALIDATING, Boolean.TRUE);
```

But the above threw an exception for me:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   true value of isValidating not
>   supported     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.PropertyManager.setProperty(PropertyManager.java:150)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.setProperty(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   com.test.test2.helper.SgmlDocumentParser.parse(SgmlDocumentParser.java:83)
>     at
>   com.test.test2.helper.Test.main(Test.java:66)

So what is wrong with my approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Sun's StAX implementation just doesn't support DTD validation. You could try using [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/) instead, it appears to support validation.