# Validating markup with StaX and DTD

Tags: java, xml, dtd, stax

I have a simple XML file and a simple DTD representing it.

I am working with the *assumption* that it is *feasible*, albeit maybe not suitable, to validate markup using a DTD (as opposed to an actual schema, which I believe is the most powerful and suitable option).

Based on this *assumption*, I figured I'd give it a try with StaX.

**Problem**

StaX doesn't seem to validate anything even when provided a valid DTD, and the XML file does not match the schema defined in the DTD.

I was expecting the code below to fail with some validation-related stack trace, instead of printing all the element names in my *foo.xml* file.

I figure there might be something very wrong with my assumptions, but I couldn't find any specific explanation in the relevant SO questions I browsed, nor in other online literature.

Code and resources below.

**foo.dtd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT foo (bar+) >
<!ATTLIST foo
    foo CDATA   #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT bar (#PCDATA) >
<!ATTLIST bar
    bar (bar|blah) #REQUIRED
>
```

**foo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo foo="foo">
<!-- attribute "blah" invalid -->
<bar bar="bar" blah="blah">bar</bar>
<!-- invalid -->
<bar />
</foo>
```

**code**

```
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();

// not sure if this is required? doens't seem to help
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_VALIDATING, "true"); 

// adding dtd
xif.setXMLResolver(
    new XMLResolver() {
        public Object resolveEntity(String publicID, String systemID, String baseURI, String namespace) throws XMLStreamException {
            if ("foo.dtd".equals(systemID)) {
                 return Main.class.getResourceAsStream("foo.dtd");
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
);
XMLStreamReader reader = null;

try {
    reader = xif.createXMLStreamReader(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("foo.xml"));
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        switch (reader.next()) {
            // prints local name just for testing 
            // - expecting this to fail at some point
            case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT: 
            System.out.println(reader.getLocalName());
        }

    }
}
finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

**Output** (was expecting some stack trace)

```
foo
bar
bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I can see is that you're testing the systemID (`"foo.dtd".equals(systemID)`) but your XML file doesn't have a system identifier pointing to the DTD.

Try adding a doctype declaration with a system identifier to your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM "foo.dtd">
<foo foo="foo">
    <!-- attribute "blah" invalid -->
    <bar bar="bar" blah="blah">bar</bar>
    <!-- invalid -->
    <bar />
</foo>
```

Also, [according to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659094/stax-how-to-set-xmlinputfactory-is-validating-to-true), you will need to use a different StAX implementation as the default doesn't support validation.

Like suggested in the answer to that question, I tried using [woodstox](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox) by adding the [woodstox 5.0.3 jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.woodstox/woodstox-core/5.0.3) and the [stax2 api 4.0.0 jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/4.0.0/) to my classpath (and adding the doctype with the system identifier to the XML) and got the expected exception:

```
foo
Nov 28, 2016 3:09:53 PM so.test2.SOTest2 main
SEVERE: null
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxValidationException: Element <bar> has no attribute "blah"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [5,5]
    at com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxValidationException.create(WstxValidationException.java:50)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.reportValidationProblem(StreamScanner.java:580)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader.reportValidationProblem(ValidatingStreamReader.java:383)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.InputElementStack.reportProblem(InputElementStack.java:849)
    at com.ctc.wstx.dtd.DTDValidatorBase.doReportValidationProblem(DTDValidatorBase.java:497)
    at com.ctc.wstx.dtd.DTDValidatorBase.reportValidationProblem(DTDValidatorBase.java:479)
    at com.ctc.wstx.dtd.DTDValidator.validateAttribute(DTDValidator.java:251)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.AttributeCollector.validateAttribute(AttributeCollector.java:729)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.InputElementStack.resolveAndValidateElement(InputElementStack.java:535)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3059)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2919)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1123)
    at so.test2.SOTest2.main(SOTest2.java:56)
```